# compiler error with calling type method that takes empty context

Tags: zig

I'm trying to call `SomeClass().call`, but am running into compiler errors.

Specifically, running tests for

```
const std = @import("std");

test "doing a thing" {
    {
        const calc_result = SomeClass().call(.{});
        try std.testing.expectEqual(calc_result, 42);
    }
}

fn SomeClass() type {
    return struct {
        fn call(context: .{}) u32 {
            _ = context;
            return 42;
        }
    };
}
```

results in the error message

```
src/test.zig:12:17: error: expected type 'type', found '@TypeOf(.{})'
        fn call(context: .{}) u32 {
                ^~~~~~~
referenced by:
    test.doing a thing: src/test.zig:5:40
    remaining reference traces hidden; use '-freference-trace' to see all reference traces
```

How do I call a generic type method that takes an empty context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is equivalent to `fn foo(value: 0) void {}`. Which is obviously wrong. A function definition cannot have values.

You need to define the type of the context:

```
const std = @import("std");

const Context = struct {
};

fn SomeClass() type {
    return struct {
        fn call(context: Context) u32 {
            _ = context;
            return 42;
        }
    };
}

test "doing a thing" {
    {
        const calc_result = SomeClass().call(.{});
        try std.testing.expectEqual(calc_result, 42);
    }
}
```

Or, use `anytype`:

```
fn call(context: anytype) u32 { ... }
```

Comment: so in other words: `.{}` is a value (specifically an empty tuple); and it doesn't have an explicit type (other than maybe `@TypeOf(.{})`) so I have to give it one, like your `Context`, or use `anytype`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: ah, ok I was hoping `.{}` had an explicit off-the-shelf type that I could use. thanks!

Comment: side note: I could also use the signature `fn call(context: void) ...` and call it like `SomeClass().call({})` to get an "empty" context

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the canonical way to do this is to:

- use `void` for the *type* of the `context` parameter
- use `{}` for the *value* of the `context` parameter

This could look like so:

```
fn call(context: void) u32 {
    _ = context;
    return 42;
}

const x = call({});
```

This pattern is used in the standard library (as of version 0.11.0), e.g. in `std.sort` *(note: this example is a little indirect)*:

- [`std.sort.max`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:sort.max) takes a `lessThan` parameter, which itself is a function that takes a `@TypeOf(context)` parameter.
- [`std.sort.asc`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:sort.asc) makes a function that can be passed as a parameter to e.g. `std.sort.max`. The return type of `std.sort.asc` is a function whose first parameter (i.e., the `@TypeOf(context)` parameter) is of type `void`.
- [the tests for `std.sort.max`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/src/std/sort.zig.html#L597) use `asc_i32` as the `lessThan` parameter, and use `{}` as the `context` parameter.

Comment: You can also use `void{}` instead of `{}` to be more descriptive.